# preparing data for vegan NMDS in R

Tags: r, subset, vegan

I'd like to run an NMDS and PERMANOVA on subsets of my data using vegan in R. My data contains a lot of zeroes and looks like this:

```
> str(invert)
'data.frame':   96 obs. of  67 variables:
 $ SampleID                       : Factor w/ 96 levels "11-1-E-1","11-1-E-2",..: 61 62 63 49 50 51 85 86 87 73 ...
 $ SampleDate                     : Factor w/ 8 levels "17-Aug-12","17-Oct-12",..: 1 1 1 6 6 6 2 2 2 4 ...
 $ Year                           : int  2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 ...
 $ Month                          : Factor w/ 4 levels "August","July",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 ...
 $ Habitat                        : Factor w/ 4 levels "epiphyte","pool",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ N                              : num  1429 143 1705 1147 212 ...
 $ S                              : int  6 2 8 9 4 5 6 8 5 5 ...
 $ Aeshnidae                      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Aeshnidae..Anax                : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Aeshnidae..Gynacantha          : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Aeshnidae..Oplonaeschna        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Anisoptera                     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ant                            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

As you can see, there are four levels of "Habitat". I would like to analyse each habitat separately. I have tried subsetting, but this means I have to do it four times (one for each habitat). Is there a more efficient way of doing it?

This is how I subsetted for the pool habitat:

```
invert[6:67] <- lapply(invert[6:67], as.numeric)
pool <- subset(invert, Habitat=="pool")

ord <- metaMDS(pool[,7:67], 
               k=2, 
               trymax = 1000, 
               autotransform = TRUE, 
               expand = FALSE, 
               plot = FALSE)

plot(ord$points[,2],ord$points[,1], type="n",
     main="Communities by month", 
     xlab="NMDS 1",
     ylab="NMDS 2", 
     xlim=c(-1.5,1.5), 
     ylim=c(-1.5,1.5))
ordisymbol(ord, pool, factor="Month", cex=1.25, rainbow=T, legend=T)

#run PERMANOVA;
adonis(pool[,8:67] ~ pool$Month)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run all the species x sites in a matrix form for your nmds, and then create a group object specifying which rows are from which habitat. 
For example, if the first 6 rows of my matrix came from urbanized areas and then the next 6 came from the rain forest I would create a grouping object like this:

```
habitattypes<-c(rep("Urbanized",16), rep("RainForest",16))
Permanova<-adonis(yourdata^0.25~habitattypes, permutations = 999, method = "bray")
```